# Can i have one foreign key to both parent and it's childs in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, primary-key, sequence, inheritance

I want to have a foreign key to reference table **and** it's children. Here's how I tried and failed:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
 id serial,
 CONSTRAINT parent_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  val text,
  constraint child_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
) INHERITS(parent);

CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial,
  foreign_id bigint REFERENCES parent(id),
  constraint testpk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Lets say we have such data:

```
parent:
|id| 
+--+
|1 | --public.parent oid
|2 | --public.child oid

child:
|id|val|
+--+---+
|2 |'a'| --public.child oid
```

what i whant to acheive is this:

```
test:
|id|foreign_id|
+--+----------+
|1 | 1        | --(from public.parent table)
|2 | 2        | --(from public.child table)
```

is there a good workaround here?

Comment: I think the only workaround is not to use Postgres `INHERITS` but "proper" inheritance via foreign keys.

Comment: You know that the `INHERITS` - even with the 2 unique constraints you have - still allows 2 rows in the tables, one in `parent` and the other in `child` with same `id`? So, even if the FK were made to work somehow, which of the 2 rows should be referred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a soultion with a help from this answer [Can i have one foreign key to both parent and it's childs in postgresql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81274/can-i-have-one-foreign-key-to-both-parent-and-its-childs-in-postgresql/81287#81276) , here's a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial,
  foreign_id bigint NOT NULL,
  constraint testpk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inheritance_constraint()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    refererColumn text;
    refererId bigint;
    parentTable text;
    parentId text;
    sqlStatement text;
    result boolean;
  BEGIN
    --check if trigger is applied for each row
    IF TG_LEVEL != 'ROW' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Triger procedure "inheritance_constraint" must be applied for each row';
    END IF;
    --check if at least two arguments are passed
    IF TG_NARGS < 3 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Triger procedure "inheritance_constraint" needs at least three arguments (% received)',TG_NARGS;
    END IF;

    refererColumn = TG_ARGV[0];
    --Pick the id
    EXECUTE 'SELECT (($1).' || refererColumn || ')::bigint ;' INTO refererId USING NEW;
    --check if argument exists
    IF refererId = NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Column % does not exists',refererColumn;
    END IF;
    --get parent table
    parentTable = TG_ARGV[1];

    --get parent table id
    parentId = TG_ARGV[2];

    --build a query
    sqlStatement = format('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM %s ', parentTable );

    --if any child tables are specified in arguments, build a checking query
    IF (TG_NARGS > 3) THEN
      sqlStatement = sqlStatement || format(' JOIN pg_class ON %s.tableoid = pg_class.oid WHERE pg_class.relname IN(',parentTable);
      FOR i IN 3..(TG_NARGS-1) LOOP
        sqlStatement = sqlStatement || '''' || TG_ARGV[i] || ''''; 
        IF i != (TG_NARGS-1) LOOP THEN
          sqlStatement = sqlStatement || ',';
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      sqlStatement = sqlStatement || ') AND';
    ELSE 
      sqlStatement = sqlStatement || ' WHERE '; 
    END IF;
    sqlStatement = sqlStatement || format(' %s = %s LIMIT 1 )::boolean;',parentId,refererId);

    --query is built

    --Now check if id exists
    EXECUTE sqlStatement INTO result;
    IF result != TRUE  THEN 
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Related id % does not exist',refererId;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_references_parent 
  BEFORE UPDATE OF foreign_id OR INSERT ON test
  FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE inheritance_constraint('foreign_id','parent','parent.id');
```

I agree, it's ugly. Hoewer [this doc page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html) states

> Specifying that another table's column REFERENCES cities(name) would
>   allow the other table to contain city names, but not capital names.
>   There is no good workaround for this case.
>
> These deficiencies will probably be fixed in some future release, but
>   in the meantime considerable care is needed in deciding whether
>   inheritance is useful for your application.

So we might not need such ugly workaround in the future

**UPDATE**

There is another workaround worth a thought- it's using views

```
CREATE TABLE all_in_one (
  id serial,
  val text,
  type text -- defines whitch class the row belongs to
);

CREATE VIEW parent_view AS SELECT id FROM all_in_one;
CREATE VIEW child_view AS SELECT id, val FROM all_in_one WHERE type = 'child';
```

With some tinkering you can even make inserts into views, so it would look like youre working with inheritance, but everything would be in a single table.

Comment: I will resist downvoting but this **is ugly**.

Comment: @ypercube of course it is, it's a * trigger trying to look like a foreign key

Comment: *"in the meantime considerable care is needed in deciding whether inheritance is useful for your application"* Why do you need inheritance?

Comment: Whether the question is hypothetical or the one with a pratical approach should make no differece to quality of answers. My question is not about the alternatives that i could use, but how to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Ditching `INHERITS` is a way of solving the issue, in my opinion. Whether it is the best or not, depends on your use of it. That's why I asked.

Comment: You got a point. There are better workarounds like making composite tables or using views, but I need to use inheritance mostly because it is already widely used in schema. @ypercube

Answer (score 2):

this is not possible out of the box. inheritance in PostgreSQL is based on individual tables, which are only logically connected through pg_inherit. Each table is still somewhat independent. Therefore you cannot create a key on the entire structure. It is only possible to reference individual tables. What you can do, however, is to write a trigger ensuring integrity. A foreign key is basically the same behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: That's why i'm asking for a workaround. Could you provide more information about this trigger? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you also could do is to set up a table where only the IDs are stored:

```
CREATE TABLE common (id serial PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then change both your `parent` and `child` so that their primary keys are also foreign keys referring to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES common (id),
    ...
);
```

Similarly, any table referring to *both* `parent` and `child`, should have a reference to `common` instead.

Of course, this means you have to change the logic how you insert data into `parent` and `child`.  This means an additional `INSERT` - it can be a part of the `function used for insertion`, can be a `trigger procedure` or a plain `INSERT` in your `application code`, all depending on your existing approach.